# Understanding the Execution Results from a while loop and System.out.println

Tags: java

Hello I'm currently having difficulty understanding the process involved in the execution of while loop with the addition of added arrays. I understand the arrays and loops its just the difficulty is with the understanding of this line of code. I have searched every source I could think of but nothing seems to help me better understand it. I ran the code in my Eclipse  and the answers are presented in my console. I just cannot figure out how are they being processed. I would be really grateful is someone could help me out, thank you.

```
      import javax.swing.JApplet;


     public class SystemExecutions extends JApplet
     {
     int x=1, y=-5, z=4; // global variables 
     int vals[] = {-6,2,-4,-8 ,-2,-3}; // global variables 

      public void init()
      {
     setView();///execution results 
     setValues();///Exact output 
      }

   public void setView()//////////////////////////////execution results 
  { boolean flag = false; 
  int count = 0; int j=0; 
  int array[] = { 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5}; 
  System.out.println( ); 
  while ((!flag) && (j < array.length-1)) 
  { if (array[j] == array[j+1] ) 
  flag=true; 
  else count++; 
  ++j; 
  System.out.println("flag " + flag + " J " + j 
  + " count "+ count); 
  } 
  System.out.println("flag " + flag + " J " + j 
  + " count "+ count); 
  } 
         /*Ouput:
            flag false J 1 count 1
            flag false J 2 count 2
            flag true J 3 count 2
            flag true J 3 count 2
         */


   public void setValues()////////////////////////////Exact output 
     {char y = 'R'; 
    z=10; 
    System.out.println("l1: "+x+" "+y+" "+z); 
    y=call1(x,y,z); 
    System.out.println("l2: "+x+" "+y+" "+z); 
    x=call2(x,vals); 
    System.out.println("l3: "+x+" "+y+" "+z); 
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) 
        System.out.println("l"+(i+4)+": "+vals[i*2]); 
      } 
      public char call1(int a, char b, int c) 
      {if (a >= c) return b; 
        else 
     { c=15; 
     z=25; 
     return 'M'; // note the single quotes 
      } 
     } 
     public int call2(int x, int [] anArray) 
     {int y = 0; 
    for (int i=anArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
    {if (anArray[i] > x) 
    {anArray[i] = x + 5;y++;} 
     } 
        x=100; 
     return y; }

     }
        /*Output:
            l1: 1 R 10
            l2: 1 M 25
            l3: 1 M 25
            l4: -6
            l5: -4
            l6: -2
          */
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint before the code that you want to check and then run the debugger and go through it step by step. Or use pencil and paper ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your response. My professor mentioned to our class about using pencil and paper.

Answer (score 0):

When the condition is met (because of the two 5's next to each other in the array Array)

```
array[j] == array[j+1]
```

and you put your flag to true, the variable j is incremented one more time, hence the difference between j and count.

Comment: Thank you for your response.It really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`if` statement and `else` without a body inside `{` and `}` mean that on the condition `if` or `else` only the next command is executed.

So, in your case, inside the loop:

```
if (array[j] == array[j+1] ) 
  flag=true; 
  else count++; 
  ++j;
```

happens so, that if the `if` is true, flag is set true and if not, `count` is calculated.
Statement `j++`is executed on every iteration of the loop, because it is not affected with the `if`and `else`pair.

That may be the confusion in here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The part was a bit difficult understanding especially when the flag is !flag and the Boolean is false.